# MemoryCache AbsoluteExpiration

Tags: c#, .net-core, memorycache

When using MemoryCache it's possible to set

- `AbsoluteExpiration`
- `AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow`

Example:

```
    cache.GetOrCreate("key", f =>
    {
         f.AbsoluteExpiration = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));
         f.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        return "item";
    });
```

Can both property be set at the same time, and the one that expires first will apply? 
Or will the last property that has been set be the "master" ?

Comment: As they are properties. Does the value of `AbsoluteExpiration` changes after setting `AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow` ? If it does, there is just one underlying value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since those properties are of interface (`ICacheEntry`) - how they behave depend on concrete implementation. If we take default `MemoryCache` (and corresponding `CacheEntry` implementation) - then yes, they both can be set and, since they both represent absolute expiration, whichever happens earlier will be in effect and the other will be ignored.